# Merge duplicate records into single record in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has duplicate rows, and i would like merge them into one single record with all distinct columns.

My code sample is as follows:

```
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ","",""),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","","NY",""),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","","","LA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 01","CA","",""),("81A02","TERR NAME 01","","","NY")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state","state1","state2"])
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows:

```
df1.show()
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|zip_code|territory_name|state|state1|state2|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|      |      |
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|     |    NY|      |
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|     |      |    LA|
|   81A02|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|      |      |
|   81A02|  TERR NAME 01|     |      |    NY|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
```

I need to merge/consolidate duplicate records based on the zip_code, and get all different state values in one row.

Expected result:

```
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|zip_code|territory_name|state|state1|state2|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|    NY|    LA|
|   81A02|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|      |    LA|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
```

Am new to pyspark and not sure how to use group / joins.  Can someone please help with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are sure that there is only 1 state, 1 state1 and 1 state2 for each zip_code territory combination, you can use the following code. The `max` function uses the string, if there is a string in the grouped data, since a non-empty string has a higher value (probably ASCII wise) then the empty string `""`

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1= sqlContext.createDataFrame([("81A01","TERR NAME 01","NJ","",""),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","","NY",""),("81A01","TERR NAME 01","","","LA"),("81A02","TERR NAME 01","CA","",""),("81A02","TERR NAME 01","","","NY")], ["zip_code","territory_name","state","state1","state2"])

df1.groupBy("zip_code","territory_name").agg(max("state").alias("state"),max("state1").alias("state1"),max("state2").alias("state2")).show()
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|zip_code|territory_name|state|state1|state2|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|   81A02|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|      |    NY|
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|    NY|    LA|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** For any unique record of `zip_code` and `territory_name`, if under any of the state column there are multiple entries, then they would be `concatenated`.

*Some explanation:* In this code I employ `RDDs`. I first divide each record into two `tuples`, with `tuple1` as a `key` and `tuple2` as a `value`. Then, I reduce by `key`. `x` corresponds to `tuple1` of `(zip_code, territory_name)` and `tuple2` contains the 3 state columns. `tuple1` is taken as`key` because we want to `group by` the distinct values of `zip_code` and `territory_name`. So, every distinct pair like `(81A01,TERR NAME 01)` , `(81A02,TERR NAME 01)` is a `key`, on the base of which we `reduce`. `Reduce` means taking every two values at one time and doing some `operation` on it and then repeating the same `operation` with this result and the next element, till the entire tuple in exhausted.

So, reduce of (1,2,3,4,5) with `+` `operation` will be - `1+2=3`, then `3+3=6` and doing `+` `operation` till the last element is reached. Thus, `6+4=10` and finally `10+5=15`. Since the tuple ended at 5, so the result is 15. This is how the `reduce` works with `+` operation. Since, here we have `strings` and not `numbers`, so concatenation will happen `A+B=AB`.

```
df1=df1.rdd.map(lambda r: ((r.zip_code, r.territory_name), (r.state, r.state1, r.state2)))\
       .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2]))\
       .map(lambda r: (r[0][0],r[0][1],r[1][0],r[1][1],r[1][2]))\
       .toDF(["zip_code","territory_name","state","state1","state2"])
df1.show()
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|zip_code|territory_name|state|state1|state2|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
|   81A01|  TERR NAME 01|   NJ|    NY|    LA|
|   81A02|  TERR NAME 01|   CA|      |    NY|
+--------+--------------+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me what is x, y here.  Will it work if i have large number of rows say thousands or lakhs?  This is a sample and in real time scenario I am expecting some 15 - 50 thousand records that need to be processed.

Comment: Hello, Yes, as long as the column structure is maintained, the code will work, irrespective of whether you have 5 Rows or 500K Rows. Let me explain the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. also performance wise, which one of the above 2 answers is better.  Any suggestions

Comment: I think the one given by `gaw` is better as it employs the optimisation of `SQL` and `DataFrames`. You can go with his code. I wanted to suggest a different way of solving the problem.

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation.